# How to add a button to run code inside LeafletJS marker?

Tags: javascript, express, button, leaflet, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a button inside a pointer which print a log to the console. This is just meant to be a test, so I can actually make the marker run a method, but I can't even get it to print text.

```js
const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);

const button = '<br/><button type="button">Click button</button>'
const clickbutton = document.querySelector("#click");
button1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log('This button works!');
});
marker.bindPopup(button);
```

When I load the page, I immediately get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

The console says this error is caused by

```js
button1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
```

but I'm not sure why it's null. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the button incorrectly.

It will be right this way:

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');

button.id = 'delete';
button.textContent = 'Delete marker';
```

In order to add a button to the page, you need to find the desired parent element and add the button as a child element:

```js
// replace this id with what you need
const buttonParrentId = 'button-parrent-id';

const buttonParrent = document.getElementById(buttonParrentId);
buttonParrent.appendChild(button);
```

Next, you can work with the button as you need:

```js
const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log('This button works!');
});

marker.bindPopup(button);
```

Result code example:

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');

button.id = 'delete';
button.textContent = 'Delete marker';

// replace this id with what you need
const buttonParrentId = 'button-parrent-id';

const buttonParrent = document.getElementById(buttonParrentId);
buttonParrent.appendChild(button);

const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map);

button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log('This button works!');
});

marker.bindPopup(button);
```

[More about `createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: I still get the **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: button.addEventListener is not a function at dataFuntion** error (the code I posted is in a dataFuntion function).

Comment: @firecode85 ahh, my mistake, one moment)

Comment: @firecode85 I changed answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! **appendChild** is returning null (**'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')'**). The problem is that there is no button parent Id as I am creating the buttons when the markers are created. I haven't specified any Id in the HTML code.

Comment: @firecode85 this is a code example so you need to write the part yourself where you are looking for the parent element (marked with comment )

Comment: @firecode85 I can modify the example as you need, if you say (id, class, etc) how can I find the parent of the button

Comment: I got it working, thank you!